# How to set a button to toggle an image with animation in android?

Tags: android, android-animation, toggle

Image is getting invisible with animation correctly but not getting visible again after clicking on the button.

```
public void jerry(View view) {

  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  ImageView sjt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

  if(sjt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
       sjt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       sjt.animate().alpha(0).rotationBy(1800).setDuration(3000);
  } else {
       sjt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       sjt.animate().alpha(1).rotationBy(1800).setDuration(3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the image again after clicking the button right?

Answer (score 0):

please use this code where **btn** is Button Object, you can get both animation perfectly by this code , if you are going with Visibility==GONE or something then it will Disappear your ImageView instantly when you call **GONE**.

```
    int i= 0;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        i=i+1;
        if (i%2==1) {
            sjt.animate().alpha(0).rotationBy(1800).setDuration(3000);
        }
        else {
            sjt.animate().alpha(1).rotationBy(1800).setDuration(3000);
        }
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if(sjt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        sjt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sjt.animate().alpha(0).rotationBy(1800).setDuration(3000);
      } else {
        sjt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sjt.animate().alpha(1).rotationBy(1800).setDuration(3000);
      }       
    }
});
```